# How can I make my tables vertically aligned in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, media-queries

I have tables which are horizontally aligned side by side on desktop view for both the resolution 1920 and 1280, when i change the screen resolution to Mobile version the tables get cluttered and overlap on each other, I want it to be vertically aligned eg. 1 table on on every row centre aligned. How can that be done ?
I have put the code for horizontal aligned in desktop version.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .table-container {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
  .table-container:first-of-type {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

.table_container {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px double white;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 272px;
}

.sub_text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: 100;
}

th {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 70px;
}

.header {
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
  }
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </thead>

                <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                    <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                </td>
                <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + Spouse/partner</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + child(ren)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + family</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2"> Org’s annual max contribution<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td> emp Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would prefer to use CSS Grid for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using a valid solution with `media queries`. Add this for screens less than or equal to `600px`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tables {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .table_container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this to enable `media queries`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Full sample code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .table-container {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
  .table-container:first-of-type {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

.table_container {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px double white;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 272px;
}

.sub_text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: 100;
}

th {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 70px;
}

.header {
  color: #0071ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tables {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .table_container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="tables">
  <div class="table_container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </thead>

      <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
        <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
      </td>
      <td> emp Only</td>
      <tr>
        <td> emp + Spouse/partner</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> emp + child(ren)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> emp + family</td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2"> Org’s annual max contribution<br>
          <span class="sub_text">
                  </span>
        </td>
        <td> emp Only</td>
        <tr>
          <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
        </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
          <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
        </td>
        <td> emp Only</td>
        <tr>
          <td> emp + dependent(s)</td>
        </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="table_container">
    <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
      <tr>
        <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>H</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table_container">
    <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
      <tr>
        <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>H</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table_container">
    <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
      <tr>
        <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>H</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```